# Unique identification of a device in Manet

Tags: network-protocols, adhoc

I am trying to implement an on-demand routing protocol in MANET. I am in the beginning phase of it by just working it out on a paper. I have a doubt, how to uniquely identify a node in a mobile ad hoc network. As the nodes keep moving in the network, the neighbors of a node keeps changing. Hence I wonder if IP address is used to identify the device how would the nodes get informed of a changed IP of a node, especially the nodes which are not in its radio coverage.

I know this is a basic level question, please help me.

Comment: I think this question should be asked in StackExchange for Network Engineering http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Every networking capable device will have a **MAC ID(address)** of it's own provided by the manufacturer. So you have to get the mac-id along with your routing information to uniquely identify a mobile device in manet
[mac-id](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)
I believe you are following [ns-tutorial](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/%E2%80%8E)